# Performing an action when the application is idle

Tags: windows, delphi

I have a very simple application with a form, a richedit and a menu. I'm trying to automatically save the text on the richedit and perform other tasks but *only* when the application is idle - when the user is not writing or the app loses focus or whatever.

I tried creating an `OnIdle` event handler from a gazillion sample codes found on the internet, but it does the opposite, it activates when I *am* using the app. This [link](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_291.asp?SK=) is an example.

I also tred with a timer and check when was the last time the user wrote to the richedit, but I rather not use a timer if possible.

Anyone knows how to detect that an application is idle and run some code when it is? I'm using delphi 7.

Comment: Your solution will surely need a timer somewhere: how else are you going to specify whether 'idle' means idle for a millisecond or idle for a couple of seconds?

Comment: idle means idle. the user is not doing anything. if you want it to be for 1 sec, then 1 sec, 1 min, then one min. then choose one doesn't make a differece

Comment: A timer is the way of doing this! Why do you not wish to use a timer? Btw, saving a small RTF document to disk takes a few milliseconds; the end-user would never notice it even if you saved it ten times a second! Also, a `TTimer` is nothing strange Borland-ish, but only a wrapper for native Win32 functionality.

Comment: because the ttimer is really not a good timer. but whatever. I'll use it. thanks

Comment: Does it matter if there is 60.1 seconds between successive save operations rather than 60.0 seconds?

Comment: @Jessica, you need to be more specific than "idle means idle." From the program's perspective, the user is idle *most of the time*. Unless the user is typing extremely fast, the program has no problem keeping up, and is actually *waiting* for the user to type more. That's why the `OnIdle` event seems so counterintuitive. It runs every time the program catches up with the user, which is *very often*. Since you've said that's not what you want, *how idle* do things need to be before you really consider it idle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend an timer also, but would "reset" the countdown (toggle off and then back on) in response to any keyboard event occurring within the richedit. That way, you aren't saving while the user is trying to type.

As Andreas pointed out, here's how to actually implement this:
*Every time the user performs some action, e.g. changes the caret pos of the editor, do Timer1.Enabled := false; Timer1.Enabled := true. This will reset the timer. In effect, the timer will never fire until there has been no user activity for the last Timer1.Interval milliseconds*

Comment: thanks Chris, I'm trying to understand. Do you want me to create a timer and check a variable, if it's `0` then write (user is idle) if it's `1` don't write, user is currently writing on the richedit. is this correct?

Comment: Every time the user performs some action, e.g. changes the caret pos of the editor, do `Timer1.Enabled := false; Timer1.Enabled := true`. This will reset the timer. In effect, the timer will never fire until there has been no user activity for the last `Timer1.Interval` milliseconds.

Comment: @Andreas - thank you, I've added your example to make the answer stronger.

Comment: Plus you should disable the timer after the text was saved. Next user action will then re-enable it.

Answer (score 1):

You might be best off with a timer.  OnIdle will fire often.  What that message means, I believe, is that all messages in the queue have been handled.  So every time you have messages processed, when its done, an OnIdle is fired.

What you could do is set a variable to a time stamp after every OnChange event in the rich edit.  Then, using a timer, check every X seconds to see if that timestamp is more than say 5 seconds old.  If it is, do your saves then.

Comment: thank you, so there is no way to do this via a windows API, messages or other ways except for a timer. OK...

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetIdleTime:DWORD;
var
  lastI : TLastInputInfo;
begin
  lastI.cbSize := SizeOf(lastI);
  GetLastInputInfo(lastI);
  Result := (gettickcount - lastI.dwTime) div 1000;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if GetIdleTime = 60 then Memo1.savetofile('C:\jgs.tmp');
end;
```

Use this

Comment: You should check for GetIdleTime >= 60, otherwise you could miss the moment.